# how to know the server(tomcat6) is shutting Down in a JSF 1.2 app

Tags: jsf, tomcat, tomcat6, jsf-1.2

I am trying to implement a alerting system in my web app which 
mails me when the tomcat is shutting down. I can do it by parsing the server logs.

But i want the *app* to mail me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29). It is called when the Tomcat is shutting down or when the application is undeployed.

Here is an example:
http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-servlet/how-to-work-with-servletcontextlistener.html